# How to update associations in Entity Framework 4.1? *VERY* strange behavior out of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Is it possible to update an association between two POCO entities in Entity Framework by directly referencing the entitie's collection properties?

For instance, should something like the following work (e.g., update the MyEntityChildren list with the new values from the repository)?

```
MyEntity.MyEntityChildren = Repository.GetChildren(/*arguments*/);
MyUnitOfWork.Commit(); //calls dBContext.SaveChanges();

public class MyEntity : ISomeInterface
{
  // public properties
  Public Virtual List MyEntityChildren {get; set;}

  public MyEntity(){
    this.MyEntityChildren = new List();
  }
}

public class Child : ISomeChildInterface
{
  Public Virtual List MyEntities {get; set;}

  public Child(){
    this.MyEntities = new List();
  }
}

public class Repository
{
  //a lot of code
  public List GetChildren(/*arguments*/)
  {
     //some LINQ expressions
  }
}
```

When we do what is described above, we get an error like the following:
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SomeRelationshipKeys'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SomeRelationshipTable'.
The statement has been terminated.

The interesting thing about this is that the error above ONLY occurs when we are running "at speed". If we step through the code in the debugger, everything works just fine.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Update: It appears that first clearing the association, then setting the list to the new collection solves this issue. This doesn't seem very elegant, but at least the motor is running again.  MyEntity.MyEntityChildren.Clear();  MyEntity.MyEntityChildren = Repository.GetChildren(). Obviously, you can't run these two commands in exactly this order but I hope you get my drift.

Comment: This is an interesting issue. I see you found a workaround, but did you figure out what caused it in the first place?

Comment: Justin - we never did find the source of the problem.  We've resorted to making explicit add and remove calls on all of our member attribute list modifications.

Comment: I'm favoriting this for later on. I'm curious about what's going on here, so if there's no activity for a while, I might add a bounty to it. You must have some sort of concurrency issue going on here, but I haven't used POCO EF enough to know more than that. Did you try using System.Diagnostics to log execution of your code? That might also prevent the issue from happening, but if it still occurs, you could at least learn a little more about what's going on.